# Finding static Methods in Laravel Docs

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having trouble navigating the Laravel documentation. I use the static method `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::make`, and I would like to find out more information about it. However, I cannot find it in the documentation page for `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator` (https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.html). I have had similar experiences with other static methods that I find in Laravel code snippets.

Where can such things be found (specifically where can documentation on `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::make` be found)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you see the actual class itself (`\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator`) in your IDE you will see this:

```
/**
* @see \Illuminate\Validation\Factory       <-- TELLS YOU WHERE TO LOOK
*/

class Validator extends Facade
{
    ...
}
```

The `make` method is in `\Illuminate\Validation\Factory` and the docs for it is found here https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Validation/Factory.html#method_make

Answer (score 2):

The class you mentioned is a so-called facade. This means that it has an underlying class. You can find more information about facades [in the official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/facades).

You can find the underlying class in the comment above the facade class.

```
/**
 * @see \Illuminate\Validation\Factory <- HERE
 */
class Validator extends Facade
...
```